# Swift/SpriteKit - Does ApplyImpluse's speed work in increments (adds to previous value each time)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite, skspritenode

I have a game with a ball node on which I use the applyImpluse() function to make move. However I have a question regarding the speed on applyImplulse(). If I had the initial speed at lets say applyImpulse(dx: -2, dy:2), and then if I programmed for when the ball hits an edge the function be run again such as applyImpulse(dx:-4, dy:4). Would the speed of the ball now be (dx: -4, dy:4) or does it get added with the previous impulse to make (dx:-6,dy:6).

Thanks

Comment: Kick a football and while it's still rolling, kick it again with the same impulse and keep on doing this over and over again. Will the ball roll faster over time or will its speed remain the same? If you don't have a football, why not simply fire up Xcode and _try_ it? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that it does add to the previous value each time.